# Error reinstalling El Capitan on iMac

Tags: hard-drive, imac, kernel-panic

I have a mid 2007 iMac. I attempted to reinstall El Capitan after a Safari problem. After downloading and attempting to install, I am unable to see the internal drive. When attempting to reboot in all of the different recovery modes, the computer seems to hang on the Apple logo screen at about 10% progress. If I let it sit it goes to sleep. I tried using the original disks which load but at the destination page my internal drive is not listed. I tried Apple support and they were no help. Saw a post about making a El Capitan installer on a flash drive but don't find an image of it. Any ideas? Thanks[image]

Comment: `launchd` failed. Possible drive corruption. Are you completely unable to reboot into the macOS installer screen? Or does the failure happen only after successfully completing an install and then rebooting?

Comment: You stated *"attempting to reboot in all of the different recovery modes"*. What does that mean? Your Mac is not capable of OS X Recovery over the Internet. Do you have any other Macs available? If so, what is the model/year and version of macOS?